# Rails 4 & Strange CSS configuration

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make an app with Rails 4. I use Bootstrap sass.

I recently changed the configuration of the app to try and see if the naming conventions that were being used in my stylesheets might have been causing me a problem.

I currently have a file called application.css.scss

That file imports all of my bootstrap files as well as all of the other files I used in my application (contained in my stylesheets folder).

It currently looks like this:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "bootstrap-slider";



@import "addresses.scss";
@import "articles.css.scss";
@import "common.css.scss";
@import "footer.css.scss";
@import "forms.css.scss";
@import "glyphs.css.scss";
@import "index.css.scss";
@import "legal.css.scss";
@import "navigation.css.scss";
@import "pages.css.scss";
@import "profiles.scss";
@import "video.css.scss";
```

I previously had files called framework_and_overrides.css.scss where I kept styles which altered bootstrap. I moved those to a file called navigation.css.scss or pages.css.scss.

Now, when I try inspecting element on part of the html that uses styles that were once in framework_and_overrides, the inspector shows a reference to a style in a file with that name. That style no longer exists - i have moved its location (the F&E file has been deleted from my application) and I have changed the content of the style).

When I run local host, the new style applies. When I deploy and check online, the inspector shows me a style tag that is no longer in the referenced location and has long since been updated.

Can anyone see what's gone wrong?

Comment: Firstly, have you clear browser's cache? Secondly, it is not really clear what your problem is. Is new style not applied?

Comment: No, I changed the font size from 30px to 20px. In local host, it refers to nav.css.scss file and shows the html in 20px. once deployed, it refers to the F&E.css.scss file (which has been deleted) and shows the html in 30px

Comment: How did you deploy to production. Have you recompiled your assets?

Comment: i mean how do you recompile assets?

Comment: I just found this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline. I've never done this - i don't know how it worked up to this point

Comment: Heroku should do that for you automatically, however I remember I used to have some issues with assets on heroku. Do you have `# require_tree.` in or similar in your application.sass file?

Comment: Hi - no, I removed it because bootstrap sass gem says not to use it. Instead, I have to import every file in the tree

Comment: You mean that the HTML which is generated in localhost and production have different style tags, i.e. with different stylesheets linked ?

Comment: No- same tag, renders differently